# python scrapy shell exception: address “'https:” not found: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.amazon.com/'
```

I got an error like below:

```
twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: address "'https:" [![enter image description here][1]][1]not found: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed.
```

and this is my below version of my scrapy version:

```
C:\>scrapy version -v
Scrapy    : 1.1.0
lxml      : 3.6.0.0
libxml2   : 2.9.0
Twisted   : 16.2.0
Python    : 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32
bit (Intel)]
pyOpenSSL : 16.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016)
Platform  : Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
```

help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Try with double quotes: `scrapy shell "https://www.amazon.com/"`

Comment: Thank you! It works now.

Comment: There's a note on this in the tutorial: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html?#extracting-data